Shutdown computer on idle
I've Openbox/Porteus on my laptop and I want to shutdown computer when idle 10 minutes. I edited "/etc/elogind/logind.conf" deleting "#" set "idleaction" to "poweroff" and, "idleactionsec" to 1min (to test). I rebooted computer but shutdown on idle didn't work.
How can I shutdown computer when idle 10 minutes?
